# eigenvalues of a product with a diagonal random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am interested in the eigenvalue spectrum of the following matrix A
A=(id+diag random) M
Where M is a given matrix with a known eigenvalue spectrum, lets say for simplicity that it is Hermitian. diag random is a diagonal random matrix where each entry is an independent random gaussian number. And id is the identity matrix. For some cases of M, such as M=id this problem is very easy. But if M is more complicated than that there seem to be no clear way to explicitly write down M's spectrum.
Any ideas how I could proceeed?

Thanks

W

Comment: Try search terms: "random matrix theory" and "stieltjes transforms"

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the stieltjes transform. I tried that. Unfortunately, the resulting diagrammatic expansion does not lead to a closed form because all the paths contribute equally, the crossing as well as non-crossing paths. That makes the problem quit hard. I tried writting down the first contributing terms, but other than a perturbative expansion did not get anywhere.

Comment: You should also look up ["free convolution"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_convolution) (multiplicative). That'll provide you with the tools to tackle this problem. In short, the densities convolve non-commutatively...

Comment: The multiplicative free convolution does seem like a promising approach. Could you maybe specify a helpful reference that uses this technique to compute spectra? Maybe a good teaching book or paper? Thanks so much!

Comment: This was "untagged". I've tagged it linear algebra, but I'm not sure that's appropriate. Further tag edits welcome.